# Отличие Tomcat и GlassFish

Tags: glassfish, tomcat

Здравствуйте.

Ответьте, пожалуйста, в чем состоит отличие серверов `GlassFish и Apache Tomcat.` Может, какой-то из этих серверов лучше, может какой-то быстрее?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Можно и по-русски. Хотя, что бы там ни говорили, программист просто обязан дружить с инглишем, иначе, рано или поздно, он застрянет в своём развитии.

Вот, пожалуй, САМЫЕ главные отличия Tomcat и Glassfish:

- Glassfish имеет EJB-контейнер, а Tomcat - нет;
- Glassfish имеет развитую admin-консоль, Tomcat - совсем простую;
- Glassfish полностью реализует спецификацию JavaEE, Tomcat - нет;
- Glassfish имеет поддержку кластеризации, а на Tomcat её надо имитировать разными средствами.

Answer (score 2):

[Вот эта](http://java.dzone.com/articles/glassfish-and-tomcat-whats-the) статья думаю вам поможет, правда, она старенькая, но основные принципы разъясняет.

Comment: А можно на русском, ну или белорусском языке статью?? )))
А то по-ненашему написано))). Я хоть и программист, но с английским не сильно дружу.